# Get the item option selected in select html from a List<int> of Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, select, dictionary

I have a collection (getAllDestinationsSale) contains the values which are listed in the 'select'

```
@{
    var getAllDestinationsSale = (List<StockDestinationZone>)ViewData["DestinationsForSale"];
}

<select id="selectDestination" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach (var destinationItem in getAllDestinationsSale)
    {
        <option value="@destinationItem.SdtId">
            @destinationItem.SdtName
        </option>
    }
 </select>
```

And one dictionary consists of integer number (Id) as Keys and a List  (Stock ids - SdtId) as Values

```
@{
    Dictionary<int, List<int>> dictDestinations = (Dictionary<int, List<int>>)ViewData["AssociatedDestinations"];
}
```

Now I would like to make the options in the select selected based on the Ids which are stored in the Values of dictionary dictDestinations - which means if the Id stored in List of the dictionary equals to the Id (@destinationItem.SdtId) in the collection getAllDestinationsSale, then it is selected.

Could you guys suggest me an idea for this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Does your `@destinationItem` has a field  `@destinationItem.SdtId` to keep instead of `value="1"` that you have specified for the `option` inside your loop?

Comment: @gjijo yes indeed, sorry for not making it clear, yes I do have the SdtId of the collection destinationItem , question edited

Comment: please check whether 
`<option value='@destinationItem.SdtId' '@dictDestinations.ContainsKey(@destinationItem.SdtId) ? "selected" : ""'> 
 @destinationItem.SdtName 
</option>`  
works for you.

Comment: @gjijo Thanks for your reply, unfortunately, the SdtId is stored in the Value of dictionary as List<int> and it may contain more than one value , could you suggest me how can I work in this case ? Thanks

Comment: Do this `@dictDestinations.Values.Any(x => x.Contains(@destinationItem.SdtId) == true) ? "selected" : ""` work?

Comment: @gjijo Thanks a lot, it worked however, for each line, I have the different Id of category for example, I have each line is each category, and each category may have one or more than 2 destinations in the combobox which in my case, I think I also have to check following the key of the dictionary, don't you think ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83534/discussion-between-gjijo-and-blue-cross).